# Yii2 include file to project

Tags: yii2

Now I have one twitter api library (TwitterAPIExchange.php). 
What I want to do is just to autoload it to project and make it available all model/controller.
Is it possible? Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your `composer.json` in `require` block this line:

```
"J7mbo/twitter-api-php": "*"
```

And in console run `composer update`.
In your models or controllers add `use TwitterAPIExchange;` and `TwitterAPIExchange` will be avaible in class.

More doc in https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/wiki